# Detect redirect in Grails

Tags: grails

At the end of my `save` action I redirect to the `show` action like this:

```
redirect(action: "show", id: exampleInstance.id)
```

In my `show` action I want to be able to detect if someone came directly to this action via a url, or if they were redirected here from another action.  I tried `request.isRedirected()` but it always returns `false`.

How do I detect if I am in an action as the result of a redirect from another action?

Comment: Same thing here (Grails 2.0.4), request.isRedirected() return false.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to display a confirmation message. Grails has a built-in feature for this kind of use-case:

http://www.grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Controllers/flash.html

Have a look at the example:

```
class BookController {

    def save() { 
        flash.message = "Welcome!" 
        redirect(action: 'home') 
    }
}
```

In the view you can print or check against `flash.message`.

Comment: I actually want to display multiple messages at the same time.  Instead of assigning a single string to `flash.message` as Grails does by default (and as you have done in your example) I assign a list to `flash.message` and add messages to that list as I go through my controller action.  If a redirect occurs there is a chance that `flash.message` may already have a message in it, so I don't want to create a new list.  Instead I want to add to the existing list.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Flash is just an arbitrary map. You can use `flash.asdf` for example.

Comment: @typoknig flash [is a map](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html) in Grails. You can put what you want on this, but will be able to obtain only in the first next request.

Comment: Yes, I realize flash is a map.  I was trying to have a map of lists, where one list is called `messages`.  Then I can display the entire contents of `flash.messages` on each page.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, isRedirect checks request attributes. It is equivalent to

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes
if(request.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.REDIRECT_ISSUED) != null){
    println "request was redirect"
}
```

Try it directly and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the Grails source that `isRedirected()` is only applicable to the `save` action, as it gets set in the `redirect()` method logic, and so wouldn't be set in the `show` action.

Instead, here are some manual options.  One is to add a flag to the `flash` object, which is then tested in the redirect action.  Since it is in flash scope it will be cleared at the end of the `show` action:

```
 def save() {
     // Do stuff
     flash.redirectFrom = "save"
     redirect(action:"show")
 }

 def show() {
     if (flash.redirectFrom) {
         // Respond to redirect
     }
     // Do other stuff
 }
```

Another option is to issue a `chain()` call instead of a `redirect()` and test for the implicit `chainModel` object.  The `chainModel` won't exist when the `show` action is requested from an external URL:

```
 def save() {
     // Do stuff
     chain(action:"show",model:[from:'show'])
 }

 def show() {
     if (chainModel) {
         // Respond to redirect
     }
     // Do other stuff
 }
```